# get the current scene returns NULL?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to reload the current scene , and the `init` is happen then `dealloc` .

i want to have a condition on the dealloc to return back if it called from the current scene.

i was trying this :

```
if ([[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] getChildByTag:16]) 
return;
```

and

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] isKindOfClass:[HelloWorldLayer class]]
```

both gives me NULL, and condition is not true.

why is that ???

my scene looks like :

```
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
     CCScene *gameScene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

    layer.tag=16;
    // add layer as a child to scene
    [gameScene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return gameScene;
}
```

how can i eliminate the dealloc when i only refresh the scene ??

Comment: not sure I understand your question completely, however: there's no way to abort a dealloc--it's a one way trip, it happens after your object has been released. You need to prevent your object(s) from being released in the first place.

Comment: i dont think thats true. return on dealloc will exit that function.

Comment: No, the object will be deallocated. In fact, when dealloc is called the runtime is just giving you the chance to release objects you are retaining, but it will deallocate your object when dealloc finishes. So when you call return, you basically tell him: its ok, you can deallocate this object now.

Comment: @sch is right, I "gare-ohn-tee". if your objects are being unexpectedly dealloc`d, you should investigate why they are being released in the first place. Are you retaining them properly? You might try activating ARC for your project which will manage your objects for you (for the most part).

Answer (score 1):

Never do this:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:self]
```

or this:

```
CCDirector* director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
[director replaceScene:director.runningScene];
```

You can not replace the current scene simply by passing self or the currently running scene to the replaceScene method. You always have to create a new instance of your CCScene class:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[MyScene scene]]
```

Be careful with the runningScene. The first time you send the runWithScene message to the director, the runningScene will always be nil. You can defer some initialization to the onEnter method:

```
-(void) onEnter
{
   // runningscene is valid in onEnter
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];
   [super onEnter];
}
```